# Bridging Header内のimport対象がnot found になる

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

NAME-Bridging-Header.h の
`#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` の部分が、file not found でエラーとなります。
また、-Bridging-Header.hに対しても、failed to import bridging header '/Users/taka/Desktop/NAMEFOLDER/NAME/NAME-Bridging-Header.h'とエラーになります。
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

【環境/経緯】
OS X El Capitan
X-code 7.3.1
AFNetworking 3.1.0

OSとX-codeをアップデート後、cocoa podでインストールしていたライブラリに対して、
コンソールで`sudo gem update`としても動かなくなったため、cocoa podを削除し、再インストールしました。
(`gem list`で表示されるcocoa〜と付くものを全て削除、`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`として再インストール。)

その後、ライブラリのアップデートに成功するも、上記エラーが出てしまいます。

【試したこと】
1. 下記サイトからBridging Headerは不要とあったため、
`#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`の部分をコメントアウトしました。しかし、同様にインストールしていたrealmのライブラリの中(Lockされている領域)のheaderファイルにエラーが発生。この部分もコメントアウトするも、連鎖的にエラーが発生、収拾がつかなくなり断念。
https://teratail.com/questions/30767

2.下記サイトを参考にあるとおりPods.xcconfigがなかったので作成するも、このサイトが参考にしているサイト内の"作成したxcconfgは、プロジェクトの"Info"タグ下にある"Configuration"で、各Configurationに関連付けます。"に該当する部分が見つからず、断念。
http://noboru.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/05/11/030049

3.下記サイトの解決法を実施するも、同様のエラーが継続して発生。
http ://qiita.com/mokemokechicken/items/6716193cfcbd0a4d8b84
(10点以上の信用度がないとリンクを貼り付けられないため、httpと:の間にスペースを挟みました)

4.下記同様の質問を参考にするも、コンパイラ設定はNAME/NAME-Bridging-Header.hとなっており、問題ないと判断。
http ://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6621/swift-bridging-header-の-import-で-file-not-found-が発生してしまう

---

本件、cocoa podを再インストールしたことで解決しました。
OSをelcaptainにした時に、cocoa podのインストール場所をデフォルトから変更しましたが、
そうではなく、rootless設定を有効にしてデフォルトの場所に再インストールしました。

Comment: いろいろな原因が考えられるのでリモートで解決するのはすごく大変です。どこかにエラーの起こるプロジェクトをそのまま公開することはできませんか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
本件、様々なところに関わってくるのですね... 

すぐにプロジェクト全体をそのままアップロードすることが非常に難しい状況です。もう一度対策を探し、アップロードできる状況になり次第、再度投稿させて頂きければと思います。
教えて頂いている立場でありながら、勝手ばかり大変申し訳ありません。

Comment: 問題自体はそんなに難しいことではないので、たぶん新しくまっさらな状態でやり直したらうまくいくと思います。ただ、GemやCocoaPodsのことをあまりよくわかっておられない様子で、Pods.xcconfigを手作業で追加したりなど現在のプロジェクトは明らかに異常な状態であると思われます。その状態のプロジェクトに対して問題点リモートで調べて修正するのはかなり不可能だということです。なので一度新しいプロジェクトで試してみてください。

Comment: @Taka.H さん、解決方法は回答として書いてください。自分の質問に自分で回答することはOKです。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。本件、解決済みにいたしました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、cocoa podを再インストールしたことで解決しました。
OSをelcaptainにした時に、cocoa podのインストール場所をデフォルトから変更しましたが、
そうではなく、rootless設定を有効にしてデフォルトの場所に再インストールしました。